# sort wordpress posts by title, ignore articles like “the”, “a”, “an”

Tags: wordpress, sorting, alphabetical

I'm sorting my posts alphabetically by Title, like so:

```
   <?php
      {
       $posts = get_posts($query_string . 
        '&orderby=title&order=asc&posts_per_page=-1');
      } 
      get_template_part( 'loop', 'category' );
    ?>
```

I'd like to exclude articles such as "the", "a", and "an" from the sort.

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know any simple way to do that but you can do this,

For achieving this you need to add a [custom meta field](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) to the post. Name it mytitle (say).

*For the new posts* you add, it is simple, you have to add your modified title(removing a, an, the from the title) in the mytitle custom field in the add posts page.

*For old posts* it is a bit tricky, you have to write a php code to retrieve the titles of the post remove 'a','an','the' from them using php preg_replace and add it to the postmeta table of your wordpress database using something like this:

```
<?php //inside loop   
$query=INSERT INTO xyz_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES ($postid, 'mytitle' $title);
$wpdb->query('$query'); ?>
```

where $postid is the post id inside the loop and $title is your modified title.

> Now you have updated all the previous posts with custom mytitle field.

Now to display, you have to use a custom loop (not the loop included in the theme).

Here is how you can make a basic custom loop to display posts sorted in order of mytitle.

```
$querystr = "
   SELECT wposts.*
   FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta
   WHERE wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id
   AND wpostmeta.meta_key = 'mytitle'
   AND wposts.post_type = 'post'
   AND wposts.post_status = 'publish'
   ORDER BY wpostmeta.meta_value ASC
   ";
```

Now you can execute the query by any means you want. Wordpres provides various methods to do so. [Here's a link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_Generic_Results)

For example you can do something like this

```
$pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);
foreach ( $pageposts as $pagepost ) 
{
    echo $pagepost->post_title;
    //do other stuff to display content, meta etc..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually achieve this by manipulating the ORDERBY clause using the `posts_orderby_request` filter, and using `TRIM` to ignore articles "the", "a", and "an". Here's an example:

```php
<?php
add_filter( 'posts_orderby_request', 'myproject_title_sort', 10, 2 );

/**
 * Ignore opening articles when sorting by Title.
 *
 * @param string   $orderby Order by parameter.
 * @param WP_Query $query   WP Query object.
 *
 * @return string
 */
function myproject_title_sort( $orderby, $query ) {
    global $wpdb;

    // Be sure to add a condition that matches your criteria (post type, archive, etc).
    // In this example, we bail early if it's an Admin query, or not a main query.
    if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() ) {
        return $orderby;
    }

    // This is another check to see if we're on a particular post type archive.
    if ( ! $query->is_post_type_archive( 'my-post-type' ) ) {
        return $orderby;
    }

    $title_col = $wpdb->posts . '.post_title';

    // Check if we are sorting by post_title.
    // You may need to use a separate `pre_get_posts` filter to sort by "title" if not already doing so.
    if ( false === strpos( $orderby, $title_col ) ) {
        return $orderby;
    }

    $ignore  = "TRIM( LEADING 'the ' FROM LOWER( TRIM( LEADING 'a ' FROM LOWER( TRIM( LEADING 'an ' FROM LOWER( $title_col ) ) ) ) ) )";
    $orderby = str_replace( $title_col, $ignore, $orderby );

    return $orderby;
}
```